# Double demountable hinge won't close

Tags: cabinets, hinges

I'm replacing the hinges on my cabinet and this hinge won't allow the cabinet door to close tight. It appears the hinge is rocking on the cabinet face when I try to push the door tight. I've tried a couple different hinges without luck.

[Hinge gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/l378mBeEQCkgzSyJi/200w.gif)

[image: hinge fit]

Answer (score 1):

It looks rather like the door is interfering (touching) with the frame somewhere. Watch the door carefully as you close it and see if it touches anywhere. Even a slight interference can cause that issue.

This can sometimes be corrected by adjusting the hinges. If that does not work you may need to add a spacer behind the hinge, maybe a couple of washers, to offset the door a little from the frame on the hinge side. That should provide enough clearance for the door without being overly noticeable.

Comment: The way the hinge works shouldn't allow the door to get in the way. Everything fits well on the hinge itself. I'll add another picture.

Comment: You've tried different hinges, the hinge in use looks fine. So unless the metal tab on the hinge is catching the wood edge of the cabinet door (which it does not appear to be doing); I think @Trevor is 100% correct. While the "hinge is designed shouldn't allow..." wont matter if the wood for the door, or the frame (at any location) is warped, even just a little bit.

Comment: 4th hinge was the trick